# How to print a int list using a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list type variable from my remote server as follows.

```
for line in stdout:
    print (line.split())

['0']
['0']
['1']
['0']
['24']
['1']
['24']
['55']
['63']
['22']
['4']
['1']
['5']
['1']
```

I need to convert this in to an int list and for that I used following.

```
print(' '.join(str(x) for x in line.split()))
```

But it gives me the output as only this.

```
[1]
```

How should I convert the whole list in to a int without dropping any values?

I need the output as follows.
[0,0,1,0,24,1,24,55,63,22,4,1,5,1]

Comment: Can you please show us the result you want

Comment: Can you please specify the input?

Comment: Please give us a sample value for `stdout` and the corresponding desired result.

Comment: you want `int` so you convert into `str`?

Comment: Voted to close for unresponsiveness with regards to input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list and append the values -

```
output = []
for line in stdout:
    output.append(int(line.split()[0]))
```

Or even better is a list comprehension -

```
output = [int(line.split()[0]) for line in stdout]
```

Either way, you get the list, and then print it -

```
print(output) # [0,0,1,0,24,1,24,55,63,22,4,1,5,1]
```

Comment: Hi @PCM, now im confused. why do you first split() a single value, to than take it out with [0] immediately? or did i missunderstood the contents of stdout?

Comment: Maybe, but I honestly, don't know the contents of stdout. I could just look at it and get it.

Comment: Probably the contents were - `0 0 1 0 24 etc...`, numbers seperated with a space.

Answer (score 0):

if your "line" looks something like this:

```
line = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

than this is what you're looking for:

```
new_list = [int(x) for x in line]
```